# gif image as a background

Tags: iphone

can we use a gif image as a background?
i want to set an gif image as a background, like some birds flying ....

can we use gif image to set as background.???

if yes than how?

thanks and regards

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question.

Comment: @marcelo
so,wat do u think it is.

c my answer ......

Comment: It looks like someone wants to load some wallpaper onto their iPhone. The fact that the other answer assumed a completely different scenario and got up-voted (not by me) suggests that the confusion is not mine alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, i got the solution.

```
UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default1.jpg"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default2.jpg"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default3.jpg"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default4.jpg"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default5.jpg"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default6.jpg"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default7.jpg"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default8.jpg"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default9.jpg"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default10.jpg"],                                      
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default11.jpg"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default12.jpg"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default13.jpg"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default14.jpg"],                                      
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"default15.jpg"], nil];
    animatedImageView.animationDuration = 3.0f;
    animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [animatedImageView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can - I assume you want an animated gif?

It's the same CSS rule as a static background.

```
body {
    background: url(animated.gif);
}
```